# VUE: How to make auto import all images from folder?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli

i trying auto import all images from folder. Under *// tested* is what i tried:

```
<template>
  <p>classical art</p>
  <img v-for="image in images" :key="image" :src="image.url" :alt="image.alt" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      name: "classical-art",
      images: [
        { url: require("../assets/images/classical-art/img-00001.jpg"), alt: "první" },
        { url: require("../assets/images/classical-art/img-00002.jpg"), alt: "druhý" },
      ],
    };
  },
};

// tested
const classicalArt = require(`../assets/images/classical-art/.jpg`)

classicalArt.forEach((image) => {
    return image;
});
</script>

<style module lang="scss"></style>
```

Im not good in this things so i will need a help with this. Probably im just stupid, but i cant make it works. If possible, i want it async (lazy) or whatever it is.

----- UPDATE:

I tried something like that, but still nothing, but with require.context i should be able do this probably:

```
<template>
  <p>classical art</p>
  <img :src="getImgUrl()" v-bind:alt="req" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      name: "classical-art",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getImgUrl() {
      var req = require.context(
        "../assets/images/classical-art/",
        false,
        /\*.jpg$/
      );
      req.keys().forEach(function (key) {
        req(key);
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style module lang="scss"></style>
```

I want when I add another image to the classical-art folder to create a new  tag automatically and display the image without having to edit the code and manually register it

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: what are you trying to do with `foreach` on `classicalArt` ? do you have any errors?

Comment: I want the images to be loaded automatically from the given folder and I don't have to register each image one by one in the URL like the one above with the 2 images. The error was that classicalArt is not defined

Comment: No, you are not stupid. You just lack the understanding of [client-server model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/First_steps/Client-Server_overview#static_sites) just like many other beginner. Basically your folders exist in a different computer(server) than the one in which your vue page will be displayed(client). You need a way to send that information from server to client, an [api or something](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Introduction)

Answer (score 0):

For image rendering you must indicate the exact url to every image, so you have to type every url manually in the correct way.

BTW, your idea can be implemented with NodeJS. Node runtime has access to the file system, so url string can be created authomatically for every file.

Vue, unfortunately, has no real access to your files, it means every your component, file or image must be imported manually.

Comment: so there is no way how to make it automatically with pure VUE right? WIth this "forEach" or other ways. Which solution will be best for this then?

Comment: Exactly. No way.

Unfortunately, I don't know any solution that might fit to implement your idea.